# Magento 2 Pre populate checkout Shipping Address guest form

Tags: forms, magento2.2.2, shipping-address, guest-checkout

I've created a component to pre populate checkout Shipping Address form after document is loaded.

I've enter the city,postcode and country on the front end and first name and last name within `quote.shippingAddress()` e.g

```
quote.shippingAddress().firstname = 'John';
quote.shippingAddress().lastname = 'Doe';
```

But it seen that it ins't populating the form itself but it's populating the object fine. look screen shoot attached the form.
[image]

The object :

[image]

As you can see when I refresh the page the object get populated but the form on first name and last name is empty.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Umar Not quite but made it work with simple javascript for loop value and trigger changes otherwise it wouldn't validate either.e.g `document.getElementsByName(field)[0].value = val;
                                $("input[name~='" + field + "']").trigger('change');`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found your way out since 2018 but for the ones who can have this problem, there is an easy way to populate this form (PHP side). You can use [plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`. On a `afterProcess` method, you would set what ever fits your need. For example :

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['prefix']['value'] = $prefix;
```

The function needs to return $jsLayout as the plugged one does.